# Reactor StepVerifier test fails with blockFirst()

Tags: project-reactor

Here is code to check duplicate names in database

```
public Mono<Void> validateDuplicateName(String name) throws RuntimeException {
    Flux<Customer> customerFlux = customerRepository.findByNameIgnoreCase(name);

    customerFlux.take(1).flatMap( customer -> {
        return Mono.error( new RuntimeException ("ABC99") );
    }).blockFirst();

    return Mono.empty();
}
```

Below is the test script to test the **validateDuplicateName** method

```
when(customerRepositoryMocked.findByNameIgnoreCase(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(Flux.just(customerMocked));
StepVerifier.create(customerValidator.validateDuplicateName(Mockito.anyString()))
        .expectErrorMatches( exception -> exception instanceof RuntimeException )
        .verify();
```

But the test fails with the below error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: ABC99
..
..
Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:93)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.blockFirst(Flux.java:2013)
        ... 34 more
```

Can I please get some help ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `StepVerifier` can actually only test the `Mono.empty()` that is systematically returned by the method. In the meantime, your use `blockFirst`, which will throw any exception emitted by the publisher, shortcircuiting the whole assertion.

Remember `StepVerifier` lets you assert what you expect will be asynchronously emitted by the sequence (including errors, in the form of `onError` signals). If the sequence can't even be created because the method creating it (`validateDuplicateName`) throws, then the `StepVerifier` is helpless.

But the real question is **why on earth would you block inside a method that has a `Mono` return type AND has a perfectly fine `Mono` source handy?** Your return `Mono` must be derived from that `customerFlux`.

You could use `then()` to switch to a `Mono<Void>`: this ignores the source's elements, but correctly propagates an error.

Answer (score 0):

In case your if `. blockFirst()` or `. block()` is inevitable and you may still want to let StepVerifier succeed without `Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error` then replace `. blockFirst()` or `. block()` with `.subscribe()`

**Change from:**

```java
public Mono<Void> validateDuplicateName(String name) throws RuntimeException {
    Flux<Customer> customerFlux = customerRepository.findByNameIgnoreCase(name);

    customerFlux.take(1).flatMap( customer -> {
        return Mono.error( new RuntimeException ("ABC99") );
    }).blockFirst();

    return Mono.empty();
}
```

**Change to:**

```java
public Mono<Void> validateDuplicateName(String name) throws RuntimeException {
    Flux<Customer> customerFlux = customerRepository.findByNameIgnoreCase(name);

    customerFlux.take(1).flatMap( customer -> {
        return Mono.error( new RuntimeException ("ABC99") );
    }).subscribe();

    return Mono.empty();
}
```

In general when `StepVerifier` fails with empty `bodyToMono` or `onStatus` --> `HttpStatusCode::isError` resulting in empty `bodyToMono` when the error doesn't have the body set, `.block()` will result in

`Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error`

upon changing the `.block()` to `.subscribe()` we can let go of this error and verify the test outcome as desired.